# Factory user service that either returns a promise or the cached data?

Tags: angularjs

I have a user service in AngualrJS that currently returns a promise:

```
        getData: function() {
            return Restangular.one('users', id).get({single: true});
        },
```

I want to add the ability to return the cached user, but don't think I can do this as one returns a promise and the other returns the actual data:

```
        getData: function() {
           if !data
            return Restangular.one('users', id).get({single: true});
           else
            return data
        },
```

What is the best way to handle this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should modify your code as below to always return a promise

```
 getData: function() {
          var deferred = $q.defer()
           if !data
            Restangular.one('users', id).get({single: true}).then(function(data){
               deferred.resolve(data);
             });
           else
            deferred.resolve(data);
            return deferred.promise;
        },
```