# angularjs service updating based on xhr

Tags: angularjs

I am having trouble using a service to authenticate against an external API, and register the updated service data in the same form submit.  I'm fairly certain it's a scope issue, but I'm pretty new to angular, and unsure how to scope things properly in the controller.

I have the following auth service defined:

```
angular.module('myapp.services', []).
  factory('AuthService', ['$http', function($http){
    var currentUser;
    var isLoggedIn = false;

    return {
      login: function(user, pass) {
        $http({method: 'GET', url:'https://some-api/api/login/'+user+'/'+pass}).
          success(function(data){
            currentUser = data;
            isLoggedIn = true;
          });
      },
      isLoggedIn: function(){ return isLoggedIn; },
      currentUser: function(){ return currentUser; }
    };
  }]);
```

I then have a basic form in a view bound to "user", and then in my controller:

```
angular.module('myapp.controllers', [])
  .controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', 'AuthService', function(scope, AuthService) {
    scope.update = function(user){
      AuthService.login(user.username, user.password);
      console.log(AuthService.currentUser());
    };
  }]);
```

On the first submit, I get "undefined" in console, on the 2nd submit, I then see the expected data in console... I've been reading about returning a promise and whatnot, just a little unclear on the precise implementation given the structure of my code...

Comment: have a look at similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17686307/factory-user-service-that-either-returns-a-promise-or-the-cached-data/17686436#17686436

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to log the user before the xhr request has completed. Try this:

```
angular.module('myapp.services', []).
factory('AuthService', ['$q', '$http', function($q, $http){
  var currentUser;
  var isLoggedIn = false;

  return {
    login: function(user, pass) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $http({method: 'GET', url:'https://some-api/api/login/'+user+'/'+pass}).
        success(function(data){
          currentUser = data;
          isLoggedIn = true;
          deferred.resolve();
        });
      return deferred.promise;
    },
    isLoggedIn: function(){ return isLoggedIn; },
    currentUser: function(){ return currentUser; }
  };
}]);
```

and then

```
angular.module('myapp.controllers', [])
.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', 'AuthService', function(scope, AuthService) {
  scope.update = function(user){
    AuthService.login(user.username, user.password).then(function() {
      console.log(AuthService.currentUser());
    });

  };
}]);
```

Comment: I had to change "return deferred" to "return deferred.promise" and then it worked. Thanks!